# I am trying to Scrape Data Using Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to get all the video links of from the pewdiepie channel. I wrote the following code, it is not showing any errors, but it is not scraping the links.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class PewSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "pew_spider"
   def start_request(self):
      urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie/videos'] 
      for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parser)

   def parser(self, response):
      links = response.css('div#contents > a#thumbnail::attr(href)')
      filepath = "./Desktop/pew.csv"
      with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
         f.writelines( [link + '/n' for link in links])

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(PewSpider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should take a look at YouTube API before trying to scrape it from website. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3

Comment: Does that mean there is nothing wrong with my code?

Comment: I didn't check but YouTube HTML code may be build with JavaScript code, so elements are not really there when you read source from https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie/videos. It's built by all the javascript afterwards. You can use headless browsers (like playwright) or scrapy-splash to help you evaluate all javascript code before selecting elements. That's why YouTube API might be easier to use in the end.